# Prevent Anchor From Jumping to Internal Link

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have this accordion built using only HTML and CSS but whenever one of the tabs on the accordion is clicked the page will jump so that the tab is at the top of the page.
Example:

```
<div id="tab-1"><a href="#tab-1" class="tab">502-831</a>
```

I'e looked around online and have tried a few solution such as `JavaScript` and `onlick` solutions but either the solution does nothing or causes the tab to stop functioning. I am using Joomla so there isn't much support for `JavaScript`. Here is the bare bones code for the accordion on jsfiddle, if you watch the scroll bar on the right when you click the accordion tab you will see it jump.

http://jsfiddle.net/1pjudu4j/4/

Comment: Works fine for me in latest Chrome (i.e. no jump).

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it jumps. I don't think your going to be able to get around this issue, as putting something like javascript:void(0) in as the href will stop the tab working. The jumping is not a bad thing, but I suspect you will need to use JS to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

I added this line code of CSS to your example and it worked as intended.

```
.accordion div:blur .content {
    display: none;
}
```

Do play around with your CSS with this in mind.

Please do note, you are not using JavaScript at all for this, therefore this has been posted in the wrong section. Please edit it and remove the "javascript" and "jquery" tags.

Comment: Gave it a try but it didn't resolve the issue sadly, thanks for the try though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Joomla, replace:

```
<a href="#tab-1" class="tab">502-831</a>
```

with:

```
<a href="<?php echo JUri::current();?>#tab-1" class="tab">502-831</a>
```

Comment: Tried it out but it causes the tabs to stop working :(, thanks for the try though.